# Microsoft setup bootstrapper has stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, installation

I'm getting an error when trying to install sharepoint 2010 on the server (windows server 2008 R2 64bit). The prerequisites installed fine, any ideas what this means?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I tried the install on 5 different servers and got the same result so it wasn't a problem on the server -  it seems to be a corrupt download file on the MS Volume Licensing site. When I ran the download using the download manager instead of the web browser download, it kept saying the file was corrupted after the download finished (tried this a few times with the same result). My solution was to download the software from the Trial download site, then use the key I had from the VL download.

The URL for the trial is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ee388573.aspx)

Comment: After working extensively with Microsoft support, we ended up using the trial download.

Answer (score 1):

**BEX64** event means a problem with DEP, Data Execution Prevention, or buffer overflow.

It's surely a problem in the downloaded software. You can try to turn off DEP temporary.

Comment: We tried turning off DEP, which didn't help. sharepoint is 64bit, so shouldn't DEP not matter?

Comment: Yes, it should: both 32 and 64 bit processes are subject to DEP. Then it could be a buffer overflow. Here's the [Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483.aspx), search for BEX there.

Comment: I didn't some more research, and even though I think it is DEP related as you mentioned, DEP cannot be turned off for 64Bit applications..."For the purposes of application compatibility when DEP is set to the OptOut policy level, it is possible to selectively disable DEP for individual 32-bit applications. However, DEP is always enabled for 64-bit applications." - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I spent weeks trying to get this to work. And it turned out to be group policy not allowing me to install. So in case that helps anyone else with the same issue.

Attempt the install, then check the windows event viewer and look for any software warnings.

Start -> Search for "Event Viewer" -> Windows Logs -> Application,

Look for an error with a yellow Esclamation mark in a triangle that occored around the same time as the install. And see why it didn't let you install.

Mine said this:

```
Access to C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\ose00020.exe has been restricted
by your Administrator by location with policy rule {34ae1087-c2cc-409f-a442-e48e70e62efb}
placed on path C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\*\*.exe.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while installing office on my PC.

After all possibility I found that there is existing Microsoft Office folder inside Program files (**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office**) I simply deleted that folder and tried to installed again its work for me.